# Find the way to factorize $s^2 - 2s + 5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that´s complicated a little bit, but I need to find the way the result end like **(s+   ) (s- )** please.
In the calculator the operations give $X_1= 1 , X_2=1 $
But I need in this way **(s+   ) (s- )**

Comment: It's irreducible (over the reals). In any case you can use the quadratic formula to get the roots $X_1,X_2$. Then you can write it as $(s-X_1)(s-X_2)$

Comment: $s^2-2s+5=(s-(1-2i))(s-(1+2i)=(s+2i-1)(s-2i-1)$

Comment: Ahm okey thanks!! The thing is the next, I have to apply partial fractions in this quadratic function, You know how??

Comment: Here, the roots are non-real. But what helps is to write the expression as $$(s-1)^2+4$$

Comment: Your calculator is wrong! Check your input!

Answer (score 0):

A way to find a solution to your problem is to use the quadratic formula in the following manner. By finding the roots to the problem you will be able to find the factors of the problem easily. So let's begin.

## Quadratic Formula

$$s=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
The equation you gave is in the following form:
$$as^2+bs+c$$
Now we can begin to solve this by doing the following substituting in the values:
$$\begin{align}s&=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\\
&=\frac{-(-2)\pm\sqrt{(-2)^2-4(1)(5)}}{2(1)} \\
&=1\pm\frac{\sqrt{4-20}}{2} \\
&= 1 \pm 2\sqrt{-1} \\
&=1 \pm 2i
\end{align}$$

The following roots are the following:
$$S_1=1+2i$$
$$S_2=1-2i$$

Therefore, you can write the solution as follows:
$$(s-(1+2i))(s+(-1+2i))$$

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method is using completing the square technique which would be more naïve then the quadratic formula by doing as so:

## Completing the Square

First you set the expression equal to $0$:

$$s^2-2s+5=0$$
Then you would get the following:
$$\begin{align} s^2-2s+1+4&=0 \\
(s-1)^2+4&=0
\end{align}$$

From here you can do the following:
$$\begin{align} (s-1)^2+4&=0 \\ (s-1)^2&=-4 \\ s-1&=\pm2i \\ s&=1\pm2i
\end{align}$$

Therefore you can rewrite the factors as such:
$$(s-(1-2i))(s+(-1+2i))$$